# fetching posts and showing on frontpage

Tags: posts, rss

I am having two sites viz. **www.a.com** and **www.a.com/b** .
Now, these are two seperate wp installations, in the same /root where 'b' is kind of an extended vertical site of 'a'.
I want to achieve the technique where I'd be able to show recent (or all that I publish) posts of B on A's front page.
The post should look like as it the usual part of A's native posts. For ex- if I post any topic title "my post" on B, then it should appear on its front page plus, it should also appear on A's frontpage. Any help?

Comment: sorry, am new! fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 (tested):**
The easiest way that wont even involve any special code is to use
wordpress rss feed... i dont know if this is the solution you are
after but it looks to be the simplest one i can think of...

**You can use: [feed2js](http://feed2js.org/index.php?s=build)**   (to build an rss "recent posts" display)

There you can enter the rss feed of the **www.a.com/b** blog and build a box
that would display recent posts.

feed2js even have some built in design features. Once done you can
simply embed the code you would be given into your template.

.

---

**Method 2 (unTested but intresting):**
i havent tried this but it should word i think... since both wordpress installation are
on the same server you should be able to include wp_load.php of **www.a.com/b** into a php file and the create a simple recent posts loop...

**assuming this is the structure in your ftp:**
*www.a.com
 - /wp-content/themes/some-theme/index.php

www.a.com/b/
 - /wp-content/themes/some-theme/index.php*

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/b/wp-load.php');
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h3><?php _e('Recent Articles', 'your_text_domain'); ?></h3>
<ul>
<?php
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query('showposts=5'); // SET AMOUNT OF POSTS TO RETRIVE

?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

.
i would to know how this worked for you...
so if you try Method b please update us.

Hope this helps,
Sagive

Comment: sure thing Sagive, I would be using second method as I have also read about this solution on - http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages , and now I believe its not that hard when I was first trying to phrase it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working mate ;)